# Is it possible to use tables within bulleted lists?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have multiple lines if tab-delimited text that I have pasted into a bulleted list.  It goes in fine after some minor editing, but when I select the tabbed data set and convert it to a table, it wants to put bullets within every cell of the table.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would guess not.

Comment: I've discovered that pasting the tab-delimited set into Excel and then copying and pasting it back into the email works, but no one should have to hack it to do that.